# What is the correct way to avoid a deadlock during windows store async file methods

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to write a function to load some data from the roaming folder on a windows 8 store app.

I get a deadlock (hang) on roamingLoad.Wait() in the Load method;

What is the correct way to do this? What is being done wrong below?

Edit: I should point out that if I step though it in the debugger it works perfectly.

And is there a way to do it without the top method becomeing async? If I do that then every calling method must say await to block until it's done no?

```
    public override bool Load(string in_FileNameAndDirectory, StreamTask in_StreamTask, bool in_PreferRoaming)
    {
        if (PreferRoaming && SupportsRoamingSave)
        {
            try
            {
                Task<bool> roamingLoad = RoamingLoadAsync(in_FileNameAndDirectory, in_StreamTask);
                roamingLoad.Wait();
                return roamingLoad.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return Load(in_FileNameAndDirectory, in_StreamTask);
    }


    private async Task<bool> RoamingLoadAsync(string inFileNameAndDirectory, StreamTask inStreamTask)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder roamingFolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await roamingFolder.GetFileAsync(inFileNameAndDirectory);

            using (Stream stream = await sampleFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                inStreamTask(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your method is synchronous. you can make `Load` method async as well and return Task. Then on finish continue with the execution of the rest.

Comment: I tried to test your code but then the VS2015 editor deadlocked again, Microsoft can't get this right either.  Your code deadlocks because you never actually started the task.  You avoid these kind of fairly inevitable and inscrutable mistakes by first realizing that any abstraction that makes threading looks easy adds five new undebuggable problems, using the Debug > Windows > Tasks debugger window to diagnose stuck tasks and applying ample helpings of cargo cult by strictly following the coding samples.  Async/await is turtles all the way down, deviating from the pattern buys pain.

Comment: Just a side note, is that really necessary to separate the GetFileAsync from OpenStreamForReadAsync and inStreamTask ? Just wrap them into one task to avoid unnecessary context switching.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct way to do this?

You're running into a [common deadlock problem](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (that I explain in full on my blog). To summarize, you should not use `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` on an asynchronous task. Instead, you should use `await`.

In order to use `await`, your method must be `async`. This means that this signature is just fundamentally incompatible with asynchronous operations:

```
public override bool Load(string in_FileNameAndDirectory, StreamTask in_StreamTask, bool in_PreferRoaming)
```

Assuming that the `bool` result is in fact important (which is certainly debatable - returning `bool` results instead of exceptions is kind of '80s, wouldn't you say?), the *correct* way to write this is to change the base class signature so that it supports asynchronous operations:

```
public override async Task<bool> LoadAsync(string in_FileNameAndDirectory, StreamTask in_StreamTask, bool in_PreferRoaming)
{
  if (PreferRoaming && SupportsRoamingSave)
  {
    try
    {
      return await RoamingLoadAsync(in_FileNameAndDirectory, in_StreamTask);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return Load(in_FileNameAndDirectory, in_StreamTask);
}
```

Comment: Won't this mean I will have to await everywhere I call this method (loadasync) in order to block until it is completed? I really just want this to be a standard non async method call (this code is invoked on a background thread anyway), I just want to call it and have it process completely and return a bool for if it failed or not.

Comment: @DanielArmstrong: Yes, you will have to `await` - that's the whole idea. You can't have a synchronous method block on an asynchronous method without entering a whole world of hacks and pain.

Comment: And to use await it has to be an async method... This will not work for me at all, the xbox 360 doesn't support async and we want the same method signatures across all platforms.

And if I use await when calling LoadAsync and make the calling function async then wont I also have to make the method calling that use await too and so on all the way to my top most method call?

Comment: @DanielArmstrong: Yes; that's the way `await` works. If your platform doesn't support `async`, then you can look into the various hacks I describe [in my recent MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) - but note that these are all hacks and do not work in all situations; the *correct* solution is to use `async` all the way (unfortunately not possible on your platform).